# What is the best way to remove dried egg from a house?

Tags: cleaning, windows, maintenance, vinyl-siding, glass

Some troglodytes egg my house anywhere from every 1-6 months, and have been doing so for the last four years. They just did it again tonight, so I have a fresh supply of drying egg to now remove.

My question is:

**What is the best way to remove dried egg from a house?**

My house is a bungalow with vinyl siding and a lot of glass windows (now all covered in layers of egg in varying states of dryness from previous attacks -- it's so frequent I can't keep up with cleaning it...).

**EDIT:** While I'm grateful for all the advice, I think this question would ultimately be more useful to everyone if future answers could deal with specific ways to remove egg -- not whether I should clean up the egg or not, or how to catch the miscreants, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Step 1: A pressure washer, done as quickly as possible. They are not expensive, going for about $100 for a basic one that will probably be adequate.

Step 2: A camera system, motion activated, to catch the miscreants when they return. Take them to court.

Step 3: Relax.

Comment: Well, yes; that said, $100 is a lot of money for a rental I'll only be in for another four months. I was hoping more for a cleaner suggestion that's especially effective against egg...

Comment: My guess is if you don't clean it off though, then your landlord may charge you for repainting when you leave.

Comment: @aendrew: Pressure washers are useful you can probably find other jobs for it, and they are also portable so you can take it with you when you move.

Comment: @Tester101 -- Not really; I'm moving from North America to the UK. Do they make dual voltage pressure washers?

Comment: @woodchips -- It was occurring before I moved in and my landlord knows about it; probably it's some prior tenants (of the "play ball hockey in the kitchen" sort) he kicked out.

At any rate, I have a friend with a pressure washer I may borrow. It's just really difficult to take any action against vandals when they use fast cars to be down the block before I even leave my house. :(

Comment: You can also rent tools like that, although rental costs are never really very low. Catching the vandals can be difficult. Would be nice if you could set up a camera that would get their license plate, but this is also an expense. Sadly, best is probably to find a better place to live.

Comment: Your hardware/big box stores also sell 'pressure nozzles' for standard hoses. It's not nearly the pressure of an actual pressure washer, but it's only $20 or so and might be plenty adequate for cleaning off the eggs.

Answer (score 7):

The nice thing about renting a place is that you don't own it.  Problems with the house are really the owner's problem, not yours.  If it were me, especially in the situation you've described, I'd call the landlord and say, 'Hey - come clean this crap up'.

I certainly wouldn't invest in supplies or materials to do it.

Take a look at your lease/rental agreement first; but *especially* if this was happening before you moved in, I wouldn't do much of anything to resolve it.

Comment: That's kind of the tact I'm taking... I think I'm going to confirm with my landlord this is acceptable so I don't have to pay damages when I move out later this summer.

Comment: How about a compromise - you agree to clean the egg off if your landlord purchases a cheap pressure washer (that remains his property when you leave)? If you tell him it's happening all the time, he would probably sympathize.

Answer (score 3):

Try something inexpensive and simple first, like dish soap or carwash soap and a brush-on-a-stick. Both dish soap and carwash soap are designed to remove sticky biological goo from relatively hard non-porous surfaces like vynil.

Answer (score 0):

I use Coke in a spray bottle. It works surprisingly well. Just make sure you soak the hell out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Dish soap and a j-cloth worked well to remove egg that was 2 days old from vinyl siding.